# What am I doing wrong when trying to find a determinant of this 4x4

Tags: matrices, determinant

I have to find the determinant of this 4x4 matrix:

$
\begin{bmatrix}
 5 & -7 & 2 & 2 \\
 0 & 3 & 0 & -4 \\
 -5 & -8 & 0 & 3 \\
 0 & -5 & 0 & -6 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

---

Here is my working which seems wrong according to the solutions. What am i doing wrong?:

---

[image]

And here is the solution:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is precisely what the solution *said* you were doing wrong. The $2$ was alright, since that's the same as $2\cdot(-1)^{1+3},$ but the $-5$ was not, since $$-5\cdot(-1)^{2+1}=-5\cdot-1=5.$$ Keep in mind that we have an alternating sign factor as we move along a row/column, and that the starting sign depends on the row/column that we're in.

Answer (score 1):

Your $3\times3$ determinant has to have a $-(-5)$ in the front. Hope you can see that from the formula of a determinant for a $3\times 3$ matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Define the   permutation matrices $P_k$ by $P_1 e_2 = e_3, P_1 e_3 = e_2$, and  $P_2 e_1 = e_3, P_2 e_2 = e_1, P_2 e_3 = e_2$ (the other basis vectors mapped to themselves). It is easy to verify that $\det P_1 = -1, \det P_2 = +1$.

Then $P_1 A P_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 5 & -7 & 2 \\
0 & -5 & -8 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 3 & -4 \\
0 & 0 & 5 & -6\end{bmatrix}$, and $\det (P_1 A P_2) = -20$, hence $\det A = 20$.